# Persistent console history in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

On 6.12.2, this just worked for me, I think. But now I'm on a new box with 6.12.3 (generic unix binary), and there's obviously some setting I'm missing.

I have a console history in ghci within a single session (i.e. execution of ghci), but this history isn't saved and reloaded between sessions, as it used to be. I can't keep track if ghci is using readline, editline, or haskeline even, so I'm not quite sure where to start in terms of fixing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might not be of much help but have you checked whether the ghci_history file is being written to in `~/.ghc/ghci_history`?

Comment: This was indeed the answer. For some reason, ghc/ghci failed to create the .ghc directory. I created the directory, and now my history gets stored there :-)

Comment: And what is the expected behavior of ghci? Should it try to create ~/.ghc if it's not there? I discovered that I can also make use of the persistent history feature (which I missed before) after I created this directory. Isn't it not nice that ghci (ghc-7.0.1-[alt1](http://prometheus.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/ghc)) doesn't create it automatically, so that I only learned *by occasion* that there can be persistent histroy in GHCi?

Comment: @imz -- I filed a ticket after I realized what was going on. It should be fixed in 7.0.3: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4522

Comment: I believe it is `~/.ghc/ghci_history`

Answer (score 0):

The [Sean Seefried's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249351/persistent-console-history-in-ghci/4251344#4251344) does not work in Windows systems because ghc has its home in `%APPDATA%\ghci` (in my case, `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\ghci`).

The file can be found in there: `ghci_history`

Comment: My file `ghci_history` on Windows is completely empty? And nothing is getting saved there?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Might it be related to permissions? Can a normal user write in there? I had no problems with that